# How to convert character(0) to NA?

Tags: r, automation

I'm automating a data pull from a table. The automation process is a not concern, but the lack of certain data values in the table is. Reference the following code below.

```
levels(droplevels(table$Votes[table$Candidate == "David Anderson"]))
```

The table I'm pulling from looks like this:

```
120 NULL                         Jim Ireton Democratic   109
121 NULL                         Joe Werner Democratic   280
122 NULL                     Cheryl Everman Democratic   213
123 NULL                      Lesley Israel Democratic   195
124 NULL                     Amanda Jackson Democratic   227
```

The table is pulled automatically and doesn't always have the "David Anderson" data value, as you see in the table above. When that happens, the end result through this code (which is meant to clean the data to a singular value) is a character(0). I'm not sure why this happens, but when it does, it makes it impossible to stick the data value into the table I'm creating. I need that value to be NA, and I'm not sure how to get it there.

Comment: `character(0)` is a character object with length 0. I guess the solution is to check for the length of the result and return that or NA, something like this: `ifelse(length(result) == 0, NA, result)`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I would do `if (length(x <- levels(droplevels(with(table, Votes[Candidate == "David Anderson"]))))) x else NA_character_`

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to store `Votes` as a `factor` in the first place? If you store `Votes` as `integer` or `numeric` this could be `with(table, if (any(idx <- Candidate == "David Anderson")) Votes[idx] else NA)`

Comment: I'm voting to close - question is not about solving problem (creating some table) but how to make one step which OP thinks is right. It's "solve X using Y" kind of question.

Comment: And translate your request to code: `if (identical(results, character(0))) results <- NA`.

Answer (score -1):

lapply(a, function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x)

Comment: If you are going to provide an answer please provide context to the answer. Just posting a string of code is not helpful in understanding why that code is the answer.